# Sencha Command + Error evaluating http://localhost/Production/app.js with message: TypeError: Cannot call method 'substring' of undefined

Tags: extjs, command, substring

Im here trying to find out how to solve this little problem.

I've been working with Sencha Touch v2.1 to create all my views and stuff.
After that, i started working with Sencha Command v3.0.0.250 to improved performance in my app, but after Sencha C. do its own business and try to open the index.html (throw IIS) something like that occurrs. (using chrome)

"Error evaluating http:// localhost/Production/app.js with message: TypeError: Cannot call method 'substring' of undefined "

Whats going on? What substring is talking about?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I forget to add that i was using the command: "sencha app build production".

I already did the "sencha app build testing", i didnt work, but no errors occurred :S WTF is going on?

Thnx in advanced!

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you see no warning messages in the Console since you have to add `requires` following by the classes you will be using before building it.